# Neural Network - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, neural-network, nested-lists

I am working on a tensorflow project, which includes a neural network that should be able to learn how to get inspirational quotes from input quotes. But when I go to run my code, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I have tried many things but am just looking for the reason it is happening. I assume it is because I am using a nested-list in my array, as seen here:

```
[list([7, 8]) list([33, 34, 34]) list([24, 4, 0, 18, 18])]
```

But I am not sure why that is causing an error as I use lists and lists of lists very frequently in my other neural networks.

Here is my full code:

```
alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " ", ".", ",", "!"]
packing = []
listing = []
try:
  while True:
    temp = input(":")
    for elements in temp:
      count = 0
      for i in range(56):
        if elements == alpha[count]:
          listing.append(count)
          break
        count = count + 1
  
    packing.append(listing)
    listing = []

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("Dataset Created.")
  print("This is your Data: " + str(packing))

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.activations import relu
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

packing = np.array(packing)
shapepack = packing.shape[0]
inputs = np.zeros((shapepack,))
print(packing)
print("--------------")
print(inputs)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(6, input_shape=(shapepack,), activation='relu',
                       kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)),
    #                                                     0.01 is the reg rate
    keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(shapepack,), activation='relu',
                       kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)),
    #                                                     0.01 is the reg rate
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(shapepack,), activation='relu',
                       kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))
    #                                                     0.01 is the reg rate
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

network = model.fit(inputs, packing, epochs=35000)

predictions = model.predict(packing)

del tf
del np
del keras
del relu
del regularizers
```

I tried to fix the error by converting the list to a float64 but I could not change the inner lists so they stayed as list type, I expected the code to work and start running the network but just ended with the same error.

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Your nested lists have not the same length. You have to padding them before converting as a tensor.

Comment: Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/pad_sequences) for padding sequences.